# Want to deploy my site in ASP.NET on to the server with SQL server used as my database

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have deployed my site on GoDaddy and its working fine but they are providing mi MySql and i have used SQL server 2008R2 so what should i do.. 
I have used Stored Procedures and all else I would have simply created my tables in MySQl

Answer (score 0):

you can't deploy mysql code on mssql server,

> get MSsql server

or

> or convert your db to my sql